# Access vector<vector<double>> and calculate the values

Tags: c++, math, vector

Say i have a `vector<vector<double>>`  that has the following list of values:

> item 1: A1 B1 C1 D1...
>   item 2: A2 B2 C2 D2...
>   item 3: A3 B3 C3 D3...

The item 1..3 belongs to the first vector and the values A..D belongs to the 2nd vector which is inside the first vector.
I need to calculate only the values from A1 to A3 and produce and display the result. Same goes for B, C and D. For now I can only access and display the values inside the `vector<vector<double>>` using iterators.
But how can I do the calculation by accessing only the values that corresponds to each other? Any suggestions?

**EDIT**
The `vector<vector<double>>` contains values like these(for example):
`v[0]={1,2,3,4,5},v[1]={2,3,4,5,6},v[2]={3,4,5,6,7}`
These vector values are stored in dynamically and the vector could contain more that just the values as shown in the above example.
I need to sum each value from each vector together and display the result. For example, First element from each vector calculated together would give me the value 6.

Comment: in your case i think `std::map` is more appropiate

Comment: Why would `std::map` be more appropriate? Doesn't `map` contains multiple  keys to its own value only?

Comment: Those values don't look like those of a `vector<vector<double>>`?

Comment: @Johnsyweb I'm sorry. I wrote it like that to make it easier for people to understand what kind of vector is that.

Comment: @JoelSeah for what i understood,you want to distinguish the element of the vector based on it's value (A, B, C). So `std::vector<std::map<std::string, double>>` where std::string can be "A", "B", "C" should be a solution for what you asked

Comment: Rather than introduce confusion with your abstraction, could you provide a concrete example of the data structure and what you mean by "calculate the values"?

Comment: @Johnsyweb I have updated the question as requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's name your vector v (the outer vector, holding vectors like so vector)
v[0] will access your first vector, which judging from your explanation, is A1->A3. You can always access vector elements using v[x] x = index, for vector of vectors, treat them as a 2D array, use v[x][y], where x = 1-3 and y = A-D, or the other way around if my interpretation is wrong.

Comment: Erm no its not like that. v[0] will access the first vector with the values A1 B1 C1 D1. What I want to do is to iterate through the vector v and calculate the values A1/2/3 from v[0] to v[2].

Comment: In that case, what you want is v[0][0], v[1][0], and v[2][0]

Comment: Your answer gave me the hint i needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely certain I got your intent correctly, but I believe what you want can be done using [`boost::zip_iterator`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/iterator/doc/zip_iterator.html).

[Here's a live example on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/85899f5d153a636c). Note that it uses C++14 for automatic deduction of the return type. It would also compile as C++11 with a warning (unless you added the trailing return type, of course, but I am lazy).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include <boost/range/iterator_range.hpp>
#include <boost/iterator/zip_iterator.hpp>

template<typename... T>
auto zip(T&... containers) {
    return boost::make_iterator_range(
        boost::make_zip_iterator(boost::make_tuple(std::begin(containers)...)),
        boost::make_zip_iterator(boost::make_tuple(std::end(containers)...))
    );
}

int main() {
    // Say we want to compute the sum, column per column, of these 3 vectors
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> v = {
        { 0.1, 1.1, 2.1, 3.1 },
        { 0.2, 1.2, 2.2, 3.2 },
        { 0.3, 1.3, 2.3, 3.3 }
    };

    // Magic
    for (auto t : zip(v[0], v[1], v[2])) {
        std::cout << t.get<0>() + t.get<1>() + t.get<2>() << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0.6
3.6
6.6
9.6
```

Comment: Yes. That's what i wanted. But the number of values in the vector is dynamic that is what that's making me crazy.

Comment: I don't understand? This solution works with any number of vectors of abritrary length, as long as all vectors have the same length.

Comment: Your for loop condition has v[0],v[1],v[2]. But the vector v could contain more vector<double>. Then I have to specify all the vectors in the for loop which wouldn't make it dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

As i saw in the comments, i think you should use std::map instead of std::vector due to the fact that you want to access the elements of the inner vector by a value (A, B, C or anythink) instead of an index (1, 2, 3, ...). So an std::vector> should be more appropriate.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
   std::vector<std::map<std::string, double>> v;
   std::map<std::string, double> m1, m2, m3;

   m1["A"]=0.0;
   m1["B"]=1.0;
   m1["C"]=2.0;

   m2["A"]=0.0;
   m2["B"]=1.0;
   m2["C"]=2.0;

   m3["A"]=0.0;
   m3["B"]=1.0;
   m3["C"]=2.0;

   v.push_back(m1);
   v.push_back(m2);
   v.push_back(m3);

   for(auto& m : v) {
       std::cout << m["A"] << std::endl;
   }
}
```

In the above example, i print all the "A" elements of the vector. In this example it will print `0.0` 3 times

Comment: Then how to add the values of "A" using that for loop? I need to be able to add all the values from each vector.

Comment: @JoelSeah what do you mean with "add the value A"? Can you make a practial example?